# Xamarin Forms Portable Project: UWP Error -2147467259

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I just created a new Xamarin App: Xaml Portable App in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Whenever I try to deploy the UWP Project I get the following error:
DEP0001: Unexpected Error: -2147467259  Project.UWP
I updated Visual Studio and all Nuget Packages, but I'm still getting the same error. I google the error code, but could not find anything useful. 
What am I doing wrong? The Project is still empty/default.

Comment: Are you on insider build or release build? I know for a fact that insider builds there was an issue with deploying code.

Comment: @AVKNaidu Nah I am on Release Build

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT DEP0001: Unexpected Error: -2147467259  as I wrote. There is nothing more

Comment: OK, then what is your xamarin version and your OS build?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Xamarin Version is 2.3.1.114 and I am trying to run Debug x86 on Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 ...

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT My office administrator ran the latest cumulative update last night on my machine, and i started receiving same error. I put a note for him to restore back to previous version to see if it fixes the problem. Now I am on 14393.105.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the Solution via Github?

Comment: @kylecorver Have you tried to type in CMD (under administrator) the following command: `net start IpOverUsbSvc`

Comment: @kylecorver Any updates? Have you tried to deploy to real device? Did this exception only occur when deploying to emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a bit older SDK and Emulator. Installed the newest ones from [Microsoft SDK Archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) - Version 10.0.14393.0 - and it works now.